# Highcharts: replace custom button image on hover

Tags: image, button, highcharts

I added a new custom button, and wanted to change it's fill when mouse hover.
Can it be done when using symbol image? 
If not I have another symbol that looks the same but has different fill color
so it will look like hovering? is there a way to replace the image upon mouseenter/mouseout?

Regards
Chanan

Comment: Here is a jFiddle example on how to add my own image to a custom button: http://jsfiddle.net/Udgb3/

Answer (score 0):

Take look at example: http://jsfiddle.net/AvpDk/

```
 normalState = new Object();
    normalState.stroke_width = null;
    normalState.stroke = null;
    normalState.fill = null;
    normalState.padding = null;
    normalState.r = null;

    hoverState = new Object();
    hoverState = normalState;
    hoverState.fill = 'red';

    pressedState = new Object();
    pressedState = normalState;

    var custombutton = chart.renderer.button('button', 74, 10, function(){
        alert('aaa');
    },null,hoverState,pressedState).add();
```

Comment: Hi
I have seen this answer before, but this has a problem when doing
zoom in zoom out (Ctrl +/-) and the button shifts from it's place.
Checking navigation buttons - they do not behave like that and they continue on being fixed in their place.

Comment: PS: if you noticed the jFiddle I have added as comment, I have a navigation button (export for example) with changed symbol - now i need to make it look like more as a button - means when mouseenter/mouseover it changes it's alpha color to 50%

Comment: or change it's fill color to same as print button