# Highcharts - Custom toggle button using the exporting buttons

Tags: highcharts

I am hoping to add toggle buttons into my highchart graphs. All is going well using the exporting plugin and an image url in the symbol options, but I am getting stuck with how to change the image depending on button state.

I am able to get the image to change if I recreate the whole graph with new options, but when I have thousands of data points displaying and I don't require the data to reload this seems like overkill.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I might achieve this?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nY4fG/1/) to show the problem

Many thanks,
Mike

```
Empty code block to bypass validation error
```

Answer (score 0):

I adivce to use renderer to add your own button, which allows to add all states like here: [Highcharts: replace custom button image on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472330/highcharts-replace-custom-button-image-on-hover)