# How to "Pause" Highcharts selection event

Tags: highcharts

Let me try to explain the meaning of "pause" a highcharts selection event :(

see this screenshoot:

[image]

when I select a range of chart area, by default a zoom animation will appear if I set "zoomType" to "x"

In this picture, when we select chart, a modal div will show on the chart, this is easy to achieve by using "chart.events.selection event", we just need to create a div element and set it to the absolute position based on mouse event ( something like clientX & clientY )

Here comes my problem:

**How to remain the blue highlight area on the chart?**

---

I have tried something like

```
e.preventDefault() // this just prevent zoom

return false // just like the above one

async function // make selection event handle async
```

not working at all, may someone help me with this? I want to achieve the result shown in the picture.

ps. I'm chinese, there may be something wrong in my grammar.

Comment: add live example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) where you did _a modal div will show on the chart,_ .It will  help for use to meet required behavior.

Comment: @Deep3015 Hello, I add a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jd4onsr7/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can add plot band in a place where selected area is.

```
chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
  from: xMin,
  to: xMax,
  color: 'rgba(209, 228, 235, 0.5)',
  id: 'plot-band-1'
});
```

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.addPlotBand

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/bjyzv6sv/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but It seems that it's not what i want, I add a jsfiddle above, I want to "pause" the selection progress, and continue it or cancel it in the modal, something rendered by react  https://jsfiddle.net/jd4onsr7/1/

Comment: I was thought that async function handle for selection event will effect, and i try 
events: {
      selection: async function(e) {
            xxx      
      }
}

Comment: Actually what I want is something like async function, when the selection trigger the handle function,  highcharts will not zoom  until the handle function return, so if I can wait in the handle function, then the blue plot band will remain automatically, instead of draw it by code

Comment: Hello, @d_paul,  I found that if I can zoom the chart by code, and with your solution, then I can achieve this goal, Is there any api that can zoom the chart initiatively?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. To zoom to a specific part of a chart you can use setExtremes() function (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.setExtremes). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ebqfn39h/.

Answer (score 0):

Taking Ideas From d_paul's post and from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22310998/3898339) post.On selection event, I am adding `plotBand` and pause button. The default reset button removes `plotBand` and button. Hope this logic is close to your requirements and also use same logic in react modal.

Code Extract

```
chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',
        events: {
          selection: function(event) {

            if ($('.pausebutton') != null) {
              $('.pausebutton').remove();
            }
            var chart = this,
            normalState = new Object();
            hoverState = new Object();
            hoverState = normalState;
            hoverState.fill = 'red';
            pressedState = new Object();
            pressedState = normalState;

            var pausebutton = chart.renderer.button('Pause', 94, 10, function() {
              disableZoom = 1;
            }, null, hoverState, pressedState).attr({
              class: 'pausebutton'
            }).add();

            if (event.resetSelection) {
              this.xAxis[0].removePlotBand('plot-band-1');
              $('.pausebutton').remove();
              disableZoom=0;
              return;
            }
            if (disableZoom == 1) {
              return false;
            }
            var xAxis = event.xAxis[0],
              plotLinesAndBands = xAxis.axis.plotLinesAndBands,
              xMin = xAxis.min,
              xMax = xAxis.max;

            // event.preventDefault();

            if (plotLinesAndBands.length > 0) {
              xAxis.axis.removePlotBand('plot-band-1');
            }

            chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
              from: xMin,
              to: xMax,
              color: 'rgba(209, 228, 235, 0.5)',
              id: 'plot-band-1'
            });

            const {
              min,
              max,
              axis
            } = event.xAxis[0];

            const x = event.originalEvent.clientX - 150;
            const y = event.originalEvent.clientY - 100;

            var dom = $(`<div class="modal-chart" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; left: ${x}px; top: ${y}px;"></div>`);

            $(document.body).append(dom);

            // I want to "pause" the selection progress here

            // and render a react component in the modal div above
            // so I can continue the selection progress 
            // or dispatch some action to redux to do some other jobs

            // ReactDOM.render(<Test></Test>, dom[0]);
          }
        }
      },
```

[Fiddle Demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/k9n3jx40/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer！Please take a look at the comment above in d_paul's post, I explain what i want actually