# Highmaps - Creating custom buttons using Exporting

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I want to create a button inside the map container of Highmap. I saw many examples which were all associated with Highcharts using Exporting. Can someone help me with an example with Highmaps(world or some particular country).
More specifically, the button is not getting created when mapbubble is used.

My sample: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffrycommvault/pbpc5r9L/)

```
exporting: {
        buttons: {
            customButton: {
                x: -62,
                onclick: function () {
                    alert('Clicked');
                },
                symbol: 'circle'
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any try from your side to have a look?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffrycommvault/pbpc5r9L/ Please, take a look.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to load exporting module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For creating buttons you can use same code as one used in Highcharts - [Highcharts: replace custom button image on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472330/highcharts-replace-custom-button-image-on-hover)

If you want to create buttons in context menu (exporting menu) then you could set them in chart's options like [`exporting.buttons`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.buttons).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6umj6veL/

**EDIT:** Do not forget to include exporting module ;)

`<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pbpc5r9L/1/

Comment: See, the button is not created only when mapbubble is used. Extreme apologies, I have add that in the question.

Comment: No problem. Add exporting module to make your code work. Answer updated.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. 
Could you please tell me how to enable "enableDoubleClickZoomTo: true" in the same bubble chart?

Comment: @jeffrycopps It works only for map area - you would have to add some data to map and enable mouse tracking: http://jsfiddle.net/qdau978v/1/